# Simple hover sub-menu disappears after reaching 3rd item

Tags: css, hover

I am currently working on making a simple hover action menu (relatively straightforward and done in previous applications).

When I hover to make the menu appear, all goes well, and I can even select the first couple of elements. However, once I reach the 3rd element (located at the edge of the larger div containing the action panel) the remaining elements are behind the later elements on the page. I have tried adjusting z-value, positioning for the hover menu is absolute, the submenu is nested within an `<li>` element, and rewritten multiple times with different html structures.

Example of HTML

```
<div>
        <menu aria-label='action menu'>
          <li><p>{'Sort by '}<span>{sortType}</span></p>
            <menu>
              <li><a href='/'>{'Sort'}</a></li>
              <li><a href='/'>{'Sort again'}</a></li>
              <li><a href='/'>{'Sorting'}</a></li>
              <li><a href='/'>{'Sorted'}</a></li>
            </menu>
          </li>
        </menu>
      </div>
```

Example of CSS:

```
> div {
    margin-right: 16px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;

    > menu {
      display: block;
      list-style: none;

      > li {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;

        > menu {
          list-style: none;
          display: list-item;
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;

          > a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
          }
        }
      &:hover {
          > menu {
            display: list-item;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            
            > li {
              display: block;

              > a {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with only that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `ol li` OR `ul li` if you are trying to make navigation or navbar. Also, you should only use `z-index`, if nothing works. That too is complicated, and it doesn't matter what z-index you give to child, the comparison is **always between the 2 html-elements that are at same level**.

If your menu is contained in a div, with `z-index: 1` and it has a sibling div which has `z-index: 2`. It will **never matter what z-index: you give to children of 1st-div**, whether 9999 or Whatever, till the parent itself has higher z-index, compared to its sibling or other html-elements at same level as it is. So, I won't suggest go with that approach.

Just use `ol li` or `ul li` and complete your task.

```css
div {
  background:yellow;
  border:2px solid #000;
  margin-right:10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

ol li {list-style-type:none;}

.list-items {display:none;}

.my-list li:hover .list-items {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ol class="my-list">
    <li>{'Sort by '}{sortType}
      <ol class="list-items">
        <li><a href='/'>{'Sort'}</a></li>
        <li><a href='/'>{'Sort again'}</a></li>
        <li><a href='/'>{'Sorting'}</a></li>
        <li><a href='/'>{'Sorted'}</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```